# How to get a module to load on boot?

Tags: drivers

so I've been following this guide for making a driver for my keyboard lighting:

[Reverse-Engineer Driver for Multi-colored Backlit Keyboard on Clevo Laptops](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184593/reverse-engineer-driver-for-multi-colored-backlit-keyboard-on-clevo-laptops)

It works but I can't seem to add it to the list of modules that load on boot.

When I try the step

```
sudo cp ~/dev/clevo-wmi-code/clevo_wmi.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/
```

it comes back to me with `target`/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/`is not a directory`.

Is there any other way for me to apply this module?

Answer (score 0):

uname -r isn't properly substituted in the directory path. You should use `$(uname -r)` in order for the right kernel version to be appended to your path.
Try the following command instead:

`sudo cp ~/dev/clevo-wmi-code/clevo_wmi.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/`

Also make sure to run `depmod -a` and to add your module name to the `/etc/modules` file.

Comment: OK, I tried that and now it says: cp: cannot stat ‘/root/dev/clevo-wmi-code/clevo_wmi.ko’: No such file or directory

Comment: Please retry by explicitly defining the path, I think that your file is in your /home/<username>/dev directory, while running a command as sudo and using the `~` character, the command will look in the home directory of the `root` user. `sudo cp /home/<username>/dev/clevo-wmi-code/clevo_wmi.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/` should do the trick in that case.

Comment: Unfortunately still no joy. The file is in home then dev. I tried inputting the command without the username but that didn't work either.